# Scaling Down Sprite Images in web pages

Tags: html, css

I have a web page. This web pages references one image file called sprites.png. This file has all of the images in one file. In side of this file I have an image that is 48px x 48px; I'm referencing it in my css like this:

```
.cell-back {
  height:36px;
  width:36px;
  border-radius:18px;
  background-color:green;
}

.play {
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background: url('/img/sprites.png') -437px 234px;
}
```

In my web page, I then have:

```
<div class="cell-back">
  <div class="play"></div>
</div>
```

As you can imagine, the "play" sprite is larger than the actually space. I'd really like for the "play" image to be 24px x 24px centered within cell-back. But, I haven't figure out how to scale down my sprite image.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use CSS transform scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `background-size` to it. This way you can scale your shown image.

```
.play {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('/img/sprites.png');
  background-position: -437px 234px;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
}
```